# Add count in joins from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting some records by joining three tables in MYSQL. The records I am getting is correct. But now I have to add one more table in this query where I have to get the unread messages for the logged in users. 
Here is the query which I am using

```
SELECT c.c_id, u.id AS user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_name, u.online_status, u.user_img, c.property_id, p.locality, p.city
FROM cpo_conversation c, property_register u, property_for_sale p
WHERE CASE WHEN c.user_one = '19'
THEN c.user_two = u.id
WHEN c.user_two = '19'
THEN c.user_one = u.id
END AND (
c.user_one = '19'
OR c.user_two = '19'
)
AND p.id = c.property_id
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

Here is my fourth table po_conversation_reply

[image: po_conversation_reply]

I want to add this table's read_unread_status count for every user who is logged in. I tried something but this is giving me the same result for every user

```
SELECT (

SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM cpo_conversation_reply
WHERE user_id_fk = u.id
AND read_unread_status =0
) AS your_count, c.c_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_name, u.online_status, c.user_one, c.user_two, u.user_img, c.property_id, p.locality, p.city
FROM cpo_conversation c, property_register u, property_for_sale p
WHERE CASE WHEN c.user_one = '19'
THEN c.user_two = u.id
WHEN c.user_two = '19'
THEN c.user_one = u.id
END AND (
c.user_one = '19'
OR c.user_two = '19'
)
AND p.id = c.property_id
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

Comment: I won't attempt an answer, but I will say that you should try to avoid the explicit joins, especially when you have so many of them.  It makes it hard to decipher the relationships between the tables.

Comment: You want to get `count` of unread message on user dashboard or admin dashboard ?

Comment: on user dashboard @PhpDeveloper

Comment: you can use something like this. `select count(read_unread_status) from table_name where  read_unread_status = 0 and user_id = session_id`

Comment: it will return same number of counts for ever row @PhpDeveloper

Comment: I don't think it should return same number, if you will filter the data by `user_id_fk` like `user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a0xhds    check this link I add screenshort of result  @PhpDeveloper

Comment: I can't not see the complete query in screenshot

Comment: SELECT (

SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM cpo_conversation_reply
WHERE user_id_fk = '19'
AND read_unread_status =0
) AS your_count, c.c_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_name, u.online_status, c.user_one, c.user_two, u.user_img, c.property_id, p.locality, p.city
FROM cpo_conversation c, property_register u, property_for_sale p
WHERE CASE WHEN c.user_one = '19'
THEN c.user_two = u.id
WHEN c.user_two = '19'
THEN c.user_one = u.id
END AND (
c.user_one = '19'
OR c.user_two = '19'
)
AND p.id = c.property_id
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
@PhpDeveloper 
This is the query